# Unable to get ImageMagick .Net working with Asp.Net 4.0

Tags: image-processing, c++-cli, image-manipulation, imagemagick

I have downloaded the **ImageMagick.Net** source code from **Codeplex** and compiled using Visual Studio 2010. It builds but when I use the generated **ImageMagickNET.dll** into my Asp.Net 4.0 application I get the following error.

```
External component has thrown an exception. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: External component has thrown an exception.

Source Error: 

Line 1049:     void Image::Read(System::String^ imageSpec)
Line 1050:     {
Line 1051:             image->read(Marshaller::SystemStringToStdString(imageSpec));
Line 1052:     }
Line 1053:

Source File: d:\dev\projects\imagemagick-63489\imagemagick.net\imagemagicknet\image.cpp    Line: 1051 

Stack Trace: 

[SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.]
   Magick.Image.read(Image* , basic_string<char\,std::char_traits<char>\,std::allocator<char> >* ) +0
   ImageMagickNET.Image.Read(String imageSpec_) in d:\dev\projects\imagemagick-63489\imagemagick.net\imagemagicknet\image.cpp:1051
   ImageMagickTest._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Sites\ImageMagickTest\ImageMagickTest\Default.aspx.cs:22
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

Has anyone got ImagMagick.Net working by compiling from the source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a bit of an old question, but this looks similar to an issue with unmatched ImageMagick versions that I was seeing.

If you are using the ImageMagickNET from their sources, you need to make sure you have ImageMagick 6.5.3-10 installed. This probably means building that release from sources, as I don't think the binaries are available anywhere (at least for Windows).

If you updated the ImageMagickNET project with sources from a new ImageMagick release, then you can use it with your newer installed version of ImageMagick. However, I experience several crashes when trying this approach with ImageMagick 6.6.6-10 on Windows. It may be that too much has changed in the underlying library for the ImageMagickNET wrapper to work correctly with this more recent version.

Comment: That was exactly it. Since i had to build it anyway, figure I might as well post it up somewhere. Feel free to download the installer: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/49525587/ImageMagick-6.5.3-10-Q16-windows-installer.zip